# Why does using pop to fill a list alter the whole list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing 16 characters. I want to use this list to fill a new list with 4 sublists. Here's what I've got:

```
alist = ['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ',', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!', ' ', '1', '2']

list4x4 = [[None]*4]*4

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        list4x4[i][j] = alist.pop(0)

print list4x4
```

This gives me

```
[['!', ' ', '1', '2'], ['!', ' ', '1', '2'], ['!', ' ', '1', '2'], ['!', ' ', '1', '2']]
```

Whereas the result I want is

```
[['H', 'e', 'l', 'l'], ['o', ',', ' ', 'w'], ['o', 'r', 'l', 'd'], ['!', ' ', '1', '2']]
```

Can someone explain what's going on here? Thanks

Comment: You have 4 references to the same list of 4 references to the same list.

Answer (score 3):

The way you constructed the list, you end up with the outer list being filled with references to the same inner list.  e.g.:

```
>>> l = [[None]*4]*4
>>> print [ id(x) for x in l ]
[39323552, 39323552, 39323552, 39323552]
```

So you can see that each inner list has the same ID -- In other words, they're all the same list.

try:

```
list4x4 = [[None]*4 for _ in range(4)]
```

Comment: @Wooble -- No.  It's fine for the inner list since `None` is immutable (and a singleton).  `[None,None,None,None]` is the same thing as `[None]*4`.  Also note that if you have a list `a = [None,None,None,None]`, you can assign to an element in that list without any problem:  `a[1] = 3`.

Comment: @Wooble The list comprehension re-evaluates that statement to produce a new sublist for each iteration.

Comment: Ah, I was mistakenly thinking `[None]*4` meant `[[None],[None],[None],[None]]`

Comment: @Wooble -- Yes, I see -- That would be a problem :)